# ActionbarSherlock with ViewPager and ActionItems disappearing

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have a tabbed 'home' activity with a ViewPager and ActionbarSherlock with ActionItems implementation that is working beautifully with the exception of one little quirk:
If I switch between the tabs too fast (i.e. starting at tab A, switch to tab B and quickly switch to tab C before the action items change) then the ActionItems disappear and will not come back until I rotate the screen or restart the app.

I've looked at the demos and there's nothing in there that's similar to what I'm doing. So I'm wondering if anybody else has experienced this and there is a **right** way of doing this.

Thanks